# Breusch-Pagan-Godfrey and estimation of sigma

Tags: regression, estimation, linear

From what I know, we usually estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i - \hat{y})^2}{n-p-1}$.

For the Breusch-Pagan-Godfrey test, my teacher told us to use $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i - \hat{y})^2}{n}$. Why do we divide by n, and not n-p-1?

($\hat{\sigma^2}$ is used to do the regression on $e_t = \frac{\hat{\epsilon}^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2}$)

Comment: can you provide some slides or teaching material, to show this? I will try to help you